# How can I print an int[] of numbers to a specific pattern?

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I am attempting to print a string of numbers to create a specific triangle pattern using an array.

I've tried for loops but int is not allowed for "006095793". Below is what I have tried already.

```
int[] array2 = {0,0,6,0,9,5,7,9,3};


int k = 006095793;

for(int i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
    k = k / 10;
    System.out.println(k);
}

System.out.println();
```

I expect the output to be

```
006095793
00609579
0060957
006095
00609
0060
006
00
0
```

Comment: integers with leading 0s represent something else. Just use the array directly.

Comment: Pro Tip: The index to your array is an int. To refer to a specific element of an array, use the corresponding index value. For example, array2[0] gives you 0. array2[2] gives you 6. array2[7] gives you 9. When you loop, you're using an ascending int value which can be used as an index value.

Comment: Tip 2: Define a separate method to get "one line" of expected output between two indexes in the array. Then you can unit-test that to make sure it works as expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array2 = { 0, 0, 6, 0, 9, 5, 7, 9, 3 };
        for (int i = array2.length; i > 0; i--) {
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                System.out.print(array2[j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
006095793
00609579
0060957
006095
00609
0060
006
00
0
```

Comment: With respect, don't be in such a rush to provide the answer to people who are clearly struggling with the fundamentals.. Provide a clue that will lead them to the answer so that they can learn something. The struggle itself is essential to the learning process. Encouraging people to work through a problem also helps future programmers become self-reliant, rather than giving up and asking for help at the first sign of trouble.

Comment: This was perfect. Exactly what I needed. Thank you.